# Динамическое выделение памяти с помощью scanf

Tags: c, массивы, память, strlen

Как с помощью `scanf` выделить память и занести в переменную.

Предположим, что пользователь вводит очень длинный текст и заранее определенный размер массива обрезает строку. Пробовал не указывать размер массива и присваивать пустую строку `("")`, но `strlen` всегда возвращает 0, а если присутствуют символы в `str`, то длину строки.

Где проблема?

```
char str[] = "";
scanf("%s",str);
printf ("Line size \"%s\" - %d characters\n", str, strlen (str) );
```

Comment: Каким это образом вы собрались изменять размер явно объявленного локального массива `str`??? Размер локального массива в С жестко фиксируется в момент объявления.

Answer (score 10):

Объявление

```
char str[] = "";
```

эквивалентно объявлению

```
char str[1] = "";
```

Массив получает размер 1, который после этого уже больше никогда не поменяется. В такой массив невозможно поместить никакую строку, кроме пустой.

В любом случае, локальный или статический массив в языке С получает конкретный фиксированный размер в точке определения. Поменять этот размер позже уже невозможно. Поэтому решить задачу чтения строки неизвестной длины с использованием явного объявления массива не получится.

Размер массива придется менять по мере необходимости, т.е. "на лету". А изменяться "на лету" может только размер динамически выделенного (через `malloc`) массива. Однако даже в этом случае какого-либо готового решения в стандартном `scanf` нет. Для чтения строк неизвестной, заранее неограниченной длины лучше использовать не `scanf`, а циклический вызов `fgets` с периодическим `realloc`-ом динамического буфера, пока не прочитана вся строка.

---

Тем не менее, GNU `scanf` поддерживает нестандартный модификатор `m`, реализующий требуемую функциональность. Этот модификатор работает с форматами `s` и `[]`:

```
char *str = NULL;
scanf("%ms", &str);
...
free(str);
```

Обратите внимание, что передавать в `scanf` в этом случае следует *указатель на указатель*, т.е. аргумент типа `char **`.

Ранее в этой роли выступал модификатор `a`. Однако начиная с C99 символ `a` "занят" под один из стандартных форматов. Поэтому если вы захотите воспользоваться этой возможностью, будьте внимательны с версией библиотеки.